java.lang.SecurityException on Ads.setBannerAd (play-services-ads)
Since we started supporting Android 14 we see the following Crash in our Firebase Crashlytics.
It crashes right after the start of the app, with the initialisation of Google Ads.
Stacktraces:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: com.COMPANY.ANDROID: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
       at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3182)
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3166)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3149)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3091)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:5784)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1853)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1793)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1781)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:756)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.zzs.zzi(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@21.1.0:4)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcnf.zzC(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@21.1.0:12)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcnf.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@21.1.0:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ClientApi.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@21.1.0:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzah.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@21.1.0:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzav.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@21.1.0:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzav.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@21.1.0:9)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzdu.zzm(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@21.1.0:11)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@21.1.0:5)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.view.ads.Ads.setBannerAd(Ads.kt:248)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.view.ads.Ads.showAds(Ads.kt:161)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.view.ads.Ads.access$showAds(Ads.kt)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.view.ads.Ads$initializeAds$1.invoke(Ads.kt:73)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.view.ads.Ads$initializeAds$1.invoke(Ads.java:70)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.view.ads.Ads$sam$androidx_lifecycle_Observer$0.onChanged(Ads.java:55)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:146)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:483)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged(LiveData.java:440)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.kt:322)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.kt:199)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:205)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.view.ads.Ads.initializeAds(Ads.kt:70)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.view.ads.Ads.<init>(Ads.kt:56)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.view.MainActivity.enableAds(MainActivity.kt:378)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.view.MainActivity.access$enableAds(MainActivity.kt:50)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.view.MainActivity$setUpObserversForAdvertisement$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:369)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.view.MainActivity$setUpObserversForAdvertisement$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.java:360)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.view.MainActivity$sam$androidx_lifecycle_Observer$0.onChanged(MainActivity.java:59)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
       at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataScopeImpl$emit$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutineLiveData.kt:100)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataScopeImpl$emit$2.invoke(CoroutineLiveData.kt:12)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataScopeImpl$emit$2.invoke(CoroutineLiveData.kt:12)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:61)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(BuildersKt__Builders_common.kt:163)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Builders.kt:1)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataScopeImpl.emit(CoroutineLiveData.kt:98)
       at androidx.lifecycle.FlowLiveDataConversions$asLiveData$1$1.emit(FlowLiveDataConversions.java:82)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.data.billing.BillingDataSource$isPurchased$$inlined$map$1$2.emit(Emitters.kt:219)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl.collect(StateFlow.kt:392)
       at com.COMPANY.ANDROID.data.billing.BillingDataSource$isPurchased$$inlined$map$1.collect(SafeCollector.common.kt:112)
       at androidx.lifecycle.FlowLiveDataConversions$asLiveData$1.invokeSuspend(FlowLiveData.kt:81)
       at androidx.lifecycle.FlowLiveDataConversions$asLiveData$1.invoke(FlowLiveData.kt:12)
       at androidx.lifecycle.FlowLiveDataConversions$asLiveData$1.invoke(FlowLiveData.kt:12)
       at androidx.lifecycle.BlockRunner$maybeRun$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutineLiveData.kt:177)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:65)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.runUnconfinedEventLoop(DispatchedTask.kt:201)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resumeUnconfined(DispatchedTask.kt:186)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:159)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:470)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:504)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:493)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:364)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharedFlowImpl.tryEmit(SharedFlow.kt:409)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharedFlowImpl.emit$suspendImpl(SharedFlow.kt)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharedFlowImpl.emit(SharedFlow.kt)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollectorKt$emitFun$1.invoke(SafeCollector.kt:11)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollectorKt$emitFun$1.invoke(SafeCollector.kt:11)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.emit(SafeCollector.kt:113)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.emit(SafeCollector.kt)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(FlowKt__Channels.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.access$emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(FlowKt__Channels.kt:1)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt$emitAllImpl$1.invokeSuspend(Channels.kt:11)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8501)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)
        

Caused by android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.registerReceiverWithFeature(ActivityManagerService.java:14337)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2615)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2798)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1496)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1440)


At the linked spots of the Stacktrace I'm setting a banner-ad from com.google.android.gms.ads
// build ad Request
val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
// Load Ad
adView.loadAd(adRequest)
Timber.d("Ad Request should be loaded")

The problem is where the loadAd(adRequest)-command is called.
Used Google-ads Version: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.1.0'

Looks like this is an internal crash in the Google AdMob library
You should update to the latest dependency 23.1.0. You can find the various version changelogs here
